# How to know user is in Settings app?

Tags: android

I would like my service to stop when the user enters the Android Settings app, then resume when the user leaves the Settings app.

Is there a system-wide flag or a broadcast that I may use?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find out which package is launching by `Activity Manager`

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();

String ClassName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getClassName();
```

You can make one background service which has a timer task of 100 seconds 
and put this code in `timertask` which prints log at every 100 seconds that which package is launching

when use is in `com.android.settings` package stop your service and when another package is running start your service.